# Function default arguments and named values

Tags: function, r

Let's say I have an R function in which the arguments can be a one of a few predefined named values (one of which is the default) or a custom character vector. How should I implement this without relying on magic value names or another flag?

```
#allow use of predefined subsets or pass their own list
bratPack<-function(members='CORE',...){
  if (members=='CORE')
    members<-c('Emilio Estevez','Anthony Michael Hall','Rob Lowe','Andrew McCarthy','Demi Moore','Judd Nelson','Molly Ringwald','Ally Sheedy')
  else if (members=='ALL')
    members<-c('Emilio Estevez','Anthony Michael Hall','Rob Lowe','Andrew McCarthy','Demi Moore','Judd Nelson','Molly Ringwald','Ally Sheedy','James Spader','Robert Downey, Jr.','Jon Cryer', 'John Cusack', 'Kevin Bacon', 'Jami Gertz', 'Mary Stuart Masterson', 'Matthew Broderick', 'Sean Penn', 'Kiefer Sutherland')
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 86):

From your example we have the choice of `"CORE"` and `"ALL"`. If those are the two options, then we specify them in the function definition for the argument `'members'`. E.g.:

```
foo <- function(x, members = c("CORE", "ALL")) {
    ## do something
}
```

That function definition sets up the allowed values for argument `'members'`, with a default of `"CORE"` as this is the first named option.

The code that one uses within the function body is `match.arg()`, as @Joris has already mentioned, but because we have set the function up as above, we can simply the usage to just `match.arg(members)`.

So we can write `foo` as:

```
foo <- function(x, members = c("CORE", "ALL")) {
    ## evaluate choices
    members <- match.arg(members)
    ## do something
    print(members)
}
```

Which we use like this:

```
> foo()
[1] "CORE"
> foo(members = "CORE")
[1] "CORE"
> foo(members = "ALL")
[1] "ALL"
> foo(members = "3rdRate")
Error in match.arg(members) : 'arg' should be one of “CORE”, “ALL”
```

Notice the behaviour when we supply an string not included in the set of options. We get an intuitive error message, all because we set up the options in the function arguments.

Comment: Having written this, I'm not sure whether you want something for the `"CORE"`, or `"ALL"` options or whether you want to store the two vectors of names somewhere. My answer addresses the former, which is what I thought of when reading the title of your Q.

Comment: I need it to accept foo("3rdRate"). Basically I am wondering what the convention is for implementing these types of predefined subsets.

Comment: @Gavin You don't have to do `members <- 'CORE'`: if you set `several.ok=T` in `match.arg()`. It will just match the first. Or simply `match.arg("CORE")` without specifying the options does the same. I chose not to specify all options in the function, as adaptation now only requires adaptation of the dataframe constant within the package. Otherwise you'll have to adapt both the data frame and the function if you want to add a new category. A matter of design I guess. Plus, using the try construct allows for specification of a vector as OP asked.

Comment: @Joris - in fact, one doesn't need `several.ok = TRUE`. `?match.arg` explains that the situation I describe is the one exception to the `‘length one unless ‘several.ok’ is ‘TRUE’’` rule. Maybe this has changed since I first learn to programme in R? Have changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: @jerdemo You are free to define where the predefined subsets are stored, either inline in the function or stored in a *hidden* object create by the code of a package at load time. If you are just writing a function for yourself, define your subsets in a list within the function, and give the list names that correspond to `"CORE"`, `"ALL"`, `"3rdRate"` etc. then use the idiom I mention in my answer to select from a predefined set of options, the options being `c("CORE", "ALL", "3rdRate")`.

Comment: @Gavin : indeed, simply `match.arg(members)` as I intended to say (too bad one can't edit comments...). I was quite surprised though to read "something not covered by Joris is how to do that in a function." I believe I did exactly that :-)

Comment: @Joris - You are right - I speed read your answer. I will edit to remove this bit as you do address this point also. I'm still not clear what the OP wants? My reading seems a little different to yours; I select one from a set of options, you allow for any number of options to be selected from a set of options.

Comment: you can pick your own brat pack members even if they are not in the predefined sets, hence the "a custom character vector"

Answer (score 12):

I'd use some constant dataframe somewhere in the package:

```
.mdata <- data.frame(
    CORE= c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),
    OLD = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
    ALL = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),
    row.names=c("John Doe", "Jan Janssen", "Piet Peters")
)

bratPack<-function(members='CORE',...){
  m.tmp <- try(
         match.arg(members,names(.mdata),several.ok=T),
         silent=T) 

  if(!is(m.tmp,"try-error"))
    members <- rownames(.mdata)[.mdata[[members]]]

  print(members)
}

> bratPack('CORE')
[1] "John Doe"    "Piet Peters"

> bratPack('Jan Janssen')
[1] "Jan Janssen"

> bratPack(c("John Doe","Dick Dickers"))
[1] "John Doe"     "Dick Dickers"
```