# Restrict argument to range of numbers

Tags: r

I am looking to restrict the values that a parameter `k` can have in R. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683405/function-default-arguments-and-named-values) example which involves restricting the value to characters but I am interested in numerical values.

To further explain what I'm looking for, `k` can be in between 1 and 10 but has a default value of 3 if no value is specified.

I know that I can do the following:

`foo <- function(k = 3) {
    #check k is in range of 1 and 10 here
    #if not in range then set it to 3
}`

I was just wondering if there's a more R-esque way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `k` is an integer, try this:

```
if (!(k %in% 1:10)) k = 3
```

If `k` is any numeric, this might help:

```
k = ifelse(k < 1 | k > 10, 3, k)
```

To make this a function as you suggest, you'd go:

```
foo <- function(k = 3) {
    k = ifelse(k < 1 | k > 10, 3, k)
    return(k)
}
```

Comment: Yeah those are helpful, I like the second one. I was looking for a solution like the example but this is a clean solution nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

Notice that there is a slight overhead with the `ifelse` function which likely does not matter. Though, for completeness this solution will do to and is faster

```
> f1 <- function(k = 3)
+   ifelse(k < 1 | k > 10, 3, k)
> 
> f2 <- function(k = 3){
+   test <- k < 1 | k > 10
+   k * (!test) + 3 * test
+ }
> 
> x <- rnorm(1e5, sd = 10)
> all.equal(f1(x), f2(x))
[1] TRUE
> 
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(x), f2(x))
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 f1(x) 7.416093 9.543104 13.464866 10.038314 10.823893 80.44003   100
 f2(x) 1.594468 2.060443  3.983543  2.224986  3.647207 71.04627   100
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing another solution but I don't understand what the line 'k * (!test) + 3 * test' does. Can you explain?

Comment: `as.numeric(FALSE)` is zero and `as.numeric(TRUE)` is one. So the above gives you either `k` or `3` depending on the value of `test`.