# Method for ascertaining if a value has been given in a function call

Tags: r

I am writing a function, there is one part of the function that can either accept a single value, or a vector, or keeps the default if nothing is specified in the function call.

In the code below "a" is given the default of 0 and then in the function there is an if statement to see if "a" is still 0 or if a value has been assigned to it.

If I call the function using a single value, a vector, or leave it blank it prints the expected result. If the vector that is given to it has a length of more than 1, I get the expected warning message (despite the function still working): 
' the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used'

My query is therefore what is the best way to test to see if "a" has been left blank and if it has been left blank to run a piece of code (in this case to print "default") or if "a" has been given a value then to run some other code (in this case to print "value given") without having the warning message if a vector is assigned to "a" when I call the function.

The example code is as below:

```
#Function
ExampleFunction<-function(a=0)

{
if  (a==0)
print ("default")
else{print("value given")}
}

#Run function using a vector which gives the warning message 
abc<-c(1,2,3)
ExampleFunction(abc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is seen because in evaluating an `if` statement, R needs a single Boolean,
not a vector of Booleans, hence the warning seen is seen when you try to send `abc <- c(1,2,3)` only the first value of vector `abc`, which is 1 gets assigned to the parameter `a` in the function. I would suggest you to read about the "Named arguments" in R.

In the meanwhile you could put a check of length of parameter `a` along with its value to see whether or not it has been assigned to a non-zero value when the function is called. Hope it helps!

Links about Named Arguments: [Function default arguments and named values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683405/function-default-arguments-and-named-values) 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tip-force-named-arguments/ 
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/r-in-a/9781449358204/ch09s05.html